# localization in Xcode 4.2

Tags: localization, xcode4.2, nslocalizedstring

I can not make a localization in an iPhone app. 
Here's what I did:

```
NSString *one = NSLocalizedString(@"Apple", @"Apple");
NSLog ("%@", one);
```

In info of application I added French. I moved the file `Localizable.strings` (UTF-16) to `fr.lproj` folder. The file contains:

```
/* Apple */
"Apple" = "Pomme";
```

I changed the language in iPhone Simulator to French, then I used Product -> Clean, and ran the project again, but it doesn't have any effect. I am getting "Apple".

What can the problem be? Maybe I'm creating `Localizable.strings` file incorrectly?

I think the problem is with Simulator, because when I added a French xib file I had the same problem, but I have no idea what is wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had learned Localizaation from [this](http://cs76.tv/2011/spring/#l=lectures&r=about&v=lectures/11/lecture11) lecture and as far as i see your code is true. Firstjy delete simulator files from your directories (probably **/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator** is its path) and compile again

Comment: i can't find this folder, i guess this path has old version of Xcode. so what kind of files?

Comment: /Users/your_user_name/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ the path to it

Comment: /Users/your_user_name then it has not any Application Support, also i tried library/application support/ but it has not any iPhone Simulator as well